# One Htpasswd For Multiple Vhosts (Apache)

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, htpasswd

I have multiple vhosts in my `httpd.conf` like this:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/wordpress"
    <Location /wp-admin/>
            AuthName "Just What Do Youuu Think You're Doing?"
            AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/.htpasswd
            AuthType basic
            require valid-user
    </Location>
...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName coolsite.example.com
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/coolsite/public"

        <Location /*>
                AuthName "Just What Do Youuu Think You're Doing?"
                AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/.htpasswd
                AuthType basic
                require valid-user
        </Location>
...
</VirtualHost
```

The first site is a WordPress - where the `.htpasswd` is meant to protect just the admin section. The second is a [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) - where the entire site is meant to be protected (`Location /*`).

The first virtual host works as intended, but the second one will continually redirect me to the htpasswd sign on screen - even when my credentials are correct... ***is this a common issue if I use the same htpasswd file for multiple vhosts?*** 
Why else could this be the case?

If I remove the `<Location /*>` from the second vhost I can access it fine... just a bit confused. The password is definitely right as it works on the first vhost.